# How can I change the path to the css file dynamically?

Tags: css, scala, lift

<head>

...

<link href="static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<lift:dynamicStile></lift:dynamicStile> //???

...

</head>

Comment: You should ask a question, say what you want, what you have tried...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll answer with the brevity of your question:

https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/master/web/webkit/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/builtin/snippet/CSS.scala